# R subset dataframe based on timestamp (1 value per hour)

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, timestamp, subset

I'm new to R and currently struggling with the following problem.

My dataframe looks like this (note that there are more columns and rows):

[transform_data_test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68lHC.png)

My goal is, to subset the dataframe so i only get 1 row per hour. Normally I should get 24 data rows per days.

I tried the following code:

```
sorting_test <- NULL
sorting_test <- transform_data_test %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd_hms(date), dt = as_date(date), hr = hour(date)) %>% 
  group_by(dt, hr) %>%
  filter(Date == min(Date)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

However, my result is missing complete data for some days and hours.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6I7m.png)

I checked multiple slack threads but couldntfind a proper solution. What am I missing?

Edit: As requested the dput of my dataframe

```
structure(list(event.id = c(8384310912, 8384310913, 8384310914, 
8384310915, 8384310916, 8384310917), visible = c("true", "true", 
"true", "true", "true", "true"), date = c("2019-01-02 14:00:23.000", 
"2019-01-02 19:00:41.000", "2019-01-03 12:40:23.000", "2019-01-03 13:20:07.000", 
"2019-01-03 13:40:07.000", "2019-01-03 14:00:06.000"), long = c(-5.8788868, 
-5.9539697, -5.8788406, -5.8780982, -5.8787327, -5.8787414), 
    lat = c(37.2227809, 37.1668986, 37.2230289, 37.2221521, 37.2229884, 
    37.223007), bar.barometric.pressure = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), data.decoding.software = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), 
    eobs.activity = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), eobs.activity.samples = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), eobs.battery.voltage = c(3706L, 3701L, 3725L, 3735L, 3730L, 
    3730L), eobs.fix.battery.voltage = c(3671L, 3666L, 3696L, 
    3710L, 3706L, 3706L), eobs.horizontal.accuracy.estimate = c(5.12, 
    5.38, 12.8, 7.94, 7.42, 7.17), eobs.key.bin.checksum = c(1795615137, 
    3161364829, 1830803994, 2772018959, 2497038035, 3520440277
    ), eobs.speed.accuracy.estimate = c(0.28, 0.3, 0.27, 0.25, 
    0.35, 0.42), eobs.start.timestamp = c("2019-01-02 13:59:57.000", 
    "2019-01-02 19:00:05.000", "2019-01-03 12:39:57.000", "2019-01-03 13:20:00.000", 
    "2019-01-03 13:40:00.000", "2019-01-03 14:00:00.000"), eobs.status = c("A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), eobs.temperature = c(18L, 11L, 
    13L, 15L, 14L, 15L), eobs.type.of.fix = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L), eobs.used.time.to.get.fix = c(25L, 35L, 25L, 6L, 
    6L, 5L), gps.dop = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), gps.satellite.count = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), ground.speed = c(0.05, 0.03, 0.07, 10.51, 0.16, 
    0.18), heading = c(0, 0, 0, 346.03, 208.4, 205.13), height.above.ellipsoid = c(108.3, 
    43.8, 106.9, 114.1, 106, 114.7), import.marked.outlier = c("false", 
    "false", "false", "false", "false", "false"), mag.magnetic.field.raw.x = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mag.magnetic.field.raw.y = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), mag.magnetic.field.raw.z = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), manually.marked.outlier = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), orientation.quaternion.raw.w = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), orientation.quaternion.raw.x = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), orientation.quaternion.raw.y = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), orientation.quaternion.raw.z = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), sensor.type = c("gps", "gps", "gps", "gps", "gps", 
    "gps"), individual.taxon.canonical.name = c("Ciconia ciconia", 
    "Ciconia ciconia", "Ciconia ciconia", "Ciconia ciconia", 
    "Ciconia ciconia", "Ciconia ciconia"), tag.local.identifier = c(3907L, 
    3907L, 3907L, 3907L, 3907L, 3907L), id = c("Mirabell + / DER AN910 (eobs 3907)", 
    "Mirabell + / DER AN910 (eobs 3907)", "Mirabell + / DER AN910 (eobs 3907)", 
    "Mirabell + / DER AN910 (eobs 3907)", "Mirabell + / DER AN910 (eobs 3907)", 
    "Mirabell + / DER AN910 (eobs 3907)"), study.name = c("LifeTrack White Stork SW Germany", 
    "LifeTrack White Stork SW Germany", "LifeTrack White Stork SW Germany", 
    "LifeTrack White Stork SW Germany", "LifeTrack White Stork SW Germany", 
    "LifeTrack White Stork SW Germany"), year = c("2019", "2019", 
    "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019"), burst = c("Mirabell   DER AN910 (eobs 3907) 2019", 
    "Mirabell   DER AN910 (eobs 3907) 2019", "Mirabell   DER AN910 (eobs 3907) 2019", 
    "Mirabell   DER AN910 (eobs 3907) 2019", "Mirabell   DER AN910 (eobs 3907) 2019", 
    "Mirabell   DER AN910 (eobs 3907) 2019")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    burst = "Mirabell   DER AN910 (eobs 3907) 2019", .rows = structure(list(
        1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Please provide you example data via `dput(df)` instead of a screenshot :)

Comment: Could you include some example rows in the df which you are incorrectly losing in the result? You don't need to include all the extra columns. Ideally the data sample should be the smallest possible that causes the problem.

Comment: @Julian already gave a helpful answer to my question. However, if you still want me to upload the example, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `distinct` helps?

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
transform_data_test %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd_hms(date), dt = as_date(date), hr = hour(date)) %>%
  group_by(burst) %>%
  distinct(dt, hr, .keep_all = T)
```

Comment: At first glance, this seems to have worked! Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: If it has in fact answered your problem, you can click the green check mark to categorize your question as answered :)